# Detect in runtime if is production code or test code in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

What is the best way to detect in runtime if the code is running a test or the production app.

Basically I want to allow a setter just for testing purposes. Something like:

```
class LoginService {

    private static var LoginService instance = LoginService();

    public var sharedInstance: LoginService {
          get{
              return instance;
          }

          set{
             if(inRunningTests()){
                 instance = newValue;
             } else {
                 fatalError("This setter is just for testing")
             } 
          }
    }        
    static func isRunningTests() -> Bool {
         // ????
    }

}
```

Comment: `#if DEBUG return true #else return false #endif`. Where `DEBUG` is defined in your project settings for the given configuration.

Comment: This is quite the code smell. Why not create a separate `MockLoginService` which shares conformance to the same new protocol as `LoginService`, and then use that for testing.

Comment: You could use polymorphism and have a `MockLoginService` for your tests, and then an actual login service of `ProdLoginService`, both inheriting from an abstract `LoginService`. Then you instantiate the right service depending on your environment: `LoginService x = (ENV == "TEST") ? new MockLoginService() : new ProdLoginService()` ... `x.doSomething()`. This uses a "tell don't ask" approach. Having lots of checks for isRunningTests isn't going to scale very well. you can use an environment variable to store what environment you're working in.

Comment: @Alexander Because the part of my code I want to replace is the Dependency manager class, and I'd like to modify it in the tests runtime to allow me inject mocks in the rest of the code (just used LoginService as example to make it easier to understand)

Comment: Are you talking about unit tests or an app being run via TestFlight?

Comment: @Adrime My point stands, make a MockDependancyManager.

Comment: @rmaddy Unit tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My working solution

```
static var isRunningTests : Bool {
    get {
        return NSClassFromString("XCTest") != nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For unit tests you can use;

```
func isTesting() -> Bool {
    if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCTestConfigurationFilePath"] == nil {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```